# remove some word from URL in yii

Tags: php, yii, yii-url-manager

Currently I have some URLs in my site that look like:

```
.com/page/about-company
.com/page/approval-license
.com/page/recruitment-areas
```

For this I have written rules in my config , like :

```
'rules' => array(

            'page/<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+>/' => 'page/view',

        ),
```

But I want to remove word *page* from those URLs. I want URLs like:

```
.com/about-company
.com/approval-license
.com/recruitment-areas
```

What can I do? please guide.

Comment: Have you tried removing the word page from the rules ? `'rules' => array('<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+>/' => 'page/view',),`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
'rules' => array(

        '<slug:[a-zA-Z0-9-_\/]+>' => 'page/view',

    ),
```

Or

```
'rules' => array(

        '<slug>' => 'page/view',

    ),
```

In this way, if your url be like `example.com/some-text`, then `view` action from `PageController` will be excuted.